# getting exactly equal clojure/clojurescript strings in UTF-8

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I have one clj file:

```
;; stringparity.clj ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
(ns stringparity)

    (defn get-java-string [input]
      (.getBytes input "UTF-8"))
```

And one cljs file:

```
;;; stringparity.cljs ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
(ns stringparity
  (:import goog.crypt))    

    (defn get-js-string [input]
      (goog.crypt.stringToUtf8ByteArray input))
```

The following code is not executable, as `get-js-string` only works in javascript, and `get-java-string` works in java; I am just pretending that you could run them in the same machine to illustrate what is going wrong. Both functions work fine when using "simple" strings, but fail when using "complex" strings like `""`. I want to be able to hash any string on either clojure or clojurescript and have their hash be the same. In order to do that, I need to be able to convert a javascript or a java string to its equivalent byte array. It appears that I am using UTF-8 for both the clojure and clojurescript side of things, but they do not generate the same byte arrays (they aren't even the same length). How do I generate the exact same byte arrays for any two equivalent strings in both clojure and clojurescript.

```
(= (seq (get-js-string "hello"))  [104, 101, 108, 108, 111]
   (seq (get-java-string "hello") [104, 101, 108, 108, 111]))


(= (seq (get-js-string ""))
   ;; when in cljs, get-js-string evaluates to the following
   [237 160 180 237 188 134]
   (seq (get-java-string ""))
   ;; when in clj, get-java-string evaluates to the following
   [-16 -99 -116 -122])
```

Answer (score 4):

The [javascript implementation](http://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git/closure_goog_crypt_crypt.js.source.html#line92) doesn't [properly handle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) characters with [codepoints above 65535.](http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi?input=%F0%9D%8C%86&mode=char)

Comment: Link rot has set in for the JS impl.

Answer (score 4):

`goog.crypt.stringToUtf8ByteArray` can't cope with characters that are represented as  "surrogate pairs" in Javascript strings (such as your "" example) and produces incorrect results.

If you don't require UTF-8 but just want a sequence of byte values to generate the hash from, one alternative would be to encode the characters as UTF-16 byte sequences in both cases:

cljs:

```
(defn to-byte [n] (if (>= n 128) (- n 256) n))

(defn get-js-string [input]
  (map to-byte
    (mapcat
      #(let [u (.charCodeAt input %)]
         [(-> (bit-and u 0xFF00) (bit-shift-right 8)) (bit-and u 0xFF)]) 
      (range (.-length input)))))
```

clj:

```
(defn get-java-string [input]
  (.getBytes input "UTF-16BE"))
```

This should give you the sequence `(-40 52 -33 6)` for your example string in both cases.